# Configuring Cyqwin to make using ./ unnecessary

Tags: shell, command-line

In order for me to run a .exe or a .sh in Cyqwin, I have to put a ./ at the beginning of my line. Is there a way for me to change this so that isn't necessary? This is causing problems when I try and run a test script and it can't find files that are right in the directory I'm working in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you must use a './' is to specifically tell the shell what file you are trying to execute. Without the leading './', your $PATH environment variable is searched. You can try adding the directories with scripts and executables you commonly use to your $PATH if you'd like. Alternatively, you can add the current directory (.) to your $PATH, but this is a Very Bad Idea as it can lead to unintentional executions.

From the [cygwin environment variables doc](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html):

> The PATH environment variable is used by Cygwin applications as a list
>   of directories to search for executable files to run. This environment
>   variable is converted from Windows format (e.g.
>   C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows) to UNIX format (e.g.,
>   /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows) when a Cygwin
>   process first starts. Set it so that it contains at least the
>   x:\cygwin\bin directory where "x:\cygwin is the "root" of your cygwin
>   installation if you wish to use cygwin tools outside of bash.

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question. Also, I discovered that the reason my test script was failing was because it was looking for files on my school's server I should have been ssh'd into.